# How is mRNA made in a lab

Tags: mrna, covid

I'm not a biologist, but I think I have a sound layman's understanding of how mRNA vaccines are made. At least this is how it was explained to me:

- create some mRNA
- get it into a cell (with the lipid nanoparticles)
- the cell uses the mRNA, sort of like a blueprint, to create a protein (like spike protein from COVID-19)
- the body sees these proteins, attacks them and learns for the next time

So far so good. But what I can not find anywhere, is a (layman, sorry) explanation of that first step: how we can create mRNA in a lab.

In a podcast (Stuff You Should Know) it was explained that it's fairly simple and they just enter the required sequence in a computer.

That's all well and good, but I'm interested in how we can actually create a specific mRNA sequence in a lab from scratch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of the COVID-19 mRNA vaccines, the mRNA is synthesized by [*in vitro* transcription](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3597572/#__sec2title). The gene of interest (*e.g.* the SARS-CoV-2 Spike protein) is [cloned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloning) into a plasmid and transcribed by RNA polymerase. The mRNA is then purified and packaged in a lipid bilayer. NHGRI has a [nice infographic](https://www.genome.gov/about-genomics/fact-sheets/COVID-19-mRNA-Vaccine-Production) explaining the full process.

RNA can also be made by [solid-phase synthesis](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/101635/52196), though this tends to be expensive and low-throughput.